# Using restartBrowserBetweenTests causes "NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator" works otherwise

Tags: protractor

My project was working fine and due to certain requirements we had to restart the browser after each test. however when i start using
restartBrowserBetweenTests flag, it is causing problems in discovering some elements - NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator

The point here is that the script works once we remove the flag but turning the flag true causes this problem. I have tried identifying places of error and adding browser.sleep() between them and the next control flow. it works when I wait explicitly for a few seconds 1-5
But doing this change in the entire codebase would not be feasible.
Can someone point me in the right direction ?

PS: Already tried, browser.restart() getting the same issue.

```
    screensaverPageHelper.verifyScreenSaverPage();
    controlFlow.execute(function () {
        //perform checkin
        dummy.performCCheckin();
        //perform delivery 
        dummyUtils.performDelivery();

        //browser.sleep(2000); // will not work without this if restartBrowserBetweenTests == true

        controlFlow.execute(function () {
            // fails on next line inside this function 
            // NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="deliveredCount"])

            dummycarrierPage.deliveredText(carrierDeliveryQRCodeStrategyPage.getDeliveredTextValue('1'));


        });
    });
```

I expected this would run without any problems with the flag restartBrowserBetweenTests

Comment: Does browser restart in the entire script you mentioned?

Comment: The browser restarts between each test cases the code above is an extract of one of the test cases. subsequent test cases also fail at the same/similar point if the flag is set "true".